# How I could pass a parameter to an CSV export method in MVC controller with Jquery/Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, csv, fileresult

On my view I have a button for export in CSV the current data view. This is a simple link to a method in the controller.

```
<input type="button" value="Exporter" id="btnexport" class="btnsearch" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("ExportCSV", "AuditAddins")'" />
```

And the controller method

```
public void ExportCSV()
{
    auditAddins = AddinsCache.AuditAddinsCache;
    var sw = new StringWriter();
        sw.WriteLine(String.Format("{0};{1};{2};{3};{4}", "Date", "AddinName", "IsAddinActive", "UserName", "PcName"));
        foreach (var record in auditAddins)
        {
            sw.WriteLine(String.Format("{0};{1};{2};{3};{4}", record.Date, record.AddinList.AddinName, record.IsAddinActive, record.Users.UserName, record.Pc.PcName));
        }
        Response.Clear();
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Export.csv");
        Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
        Response.Write(sw);
        Response.End();
}
```

It's working well. But I need to send a parameter to this method, because I have three design mode, and each have their own column order. So I have created a jquery/ajax script to send the paramater.

```
$("#btnexport").click(function () {
    var index = $('#CritID').find('option:selected').val();
    var d = { chx: index}
    $.ajax({
        url: "/AuditAddins/ExportCSV",
        type: "POST",
        data: d,
        success: function (data) {
            alert("Export ok !");
        },
    });
});
```

The main objective is to change the export method like that :

```
 public void ExportCSV(int chx)
    {
        ...
        switch (chx)
        {
            case 1:
                sw.WriteLine(String.Format("{0};{1};{2};{3};{4}", "Date", "AddinName", "IsAddinActive", "UserName", "PcName"));
                break;
            case 2:
                sw.WriteLine(String.Format("{0};{1};{2};{3};{4}", "Date", "UserName", "PcName","AddinName", "IsAddinActive"));
                break;
            ...
        }
```

The problem is that I don't have IE download window anymore. I have tried with actionresult method, it's doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use `POST` to send a parameter.

Instead, you can add a parameter to the `GET` request:

```
/AuditAddins/ExportCSV?index=2
```

and default to 1 if no parameter is provided.

To send multiple parameters, you can use `&` to separate them:

```
/AuditAddins/ExportCSV?index=2&param2=123
```

This should also solve the problem with the download window.

Comment: I have tried with :     var url = "/AuditAddins/ExportCSV?chx=1";
    $.get(url, null, function (data) {
        alert("done");
    }); But it's not working.

Comment: @mrplume - Did you process/handle that parameter on the server side too?

Comment: Yes. I have breakpoints, and I see that the paramater works, and the csv creation too. But I don't understand why IE little download popup doesn't show up.

Comment: @mrplume - That's strange - it should work exactly the same as without the parameter. Does the csv get displayed in the browser instead?

Comment: No... nothing happens. I'm using a .done(function (result) {alert("done");}); does I need to change alert("done") ? I'm really need Jquery to get the value of mode dropdownlist (this is the parameter).